# How to get the Datetime when a task is marked as done in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm developing a maintenance app, I can add tasks and get the exact time when it was created by implementing this:

```
created_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Date', auto_now_add=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

I have a field called done:

```
done = models.BooleanField(db_column='Done', default=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

Now what I need is to, when I set the done to 'True' it gives me the date and time at that moment, how can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "when I set the done to 'True' it gives me the date and time at that moment". Are you wanting an action to happen when done is set to `True`?

Comment: Sorry for my english.. What I need is when I click on a button to set the task as done, it saves the date and time at that moment into a field called "completed_date" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method within the model and call that

```
class MyModel (models.Model):
    done = models.BooleanField(db_column='Done', default=False)
    complete_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def set_done(self):
        self.done = True
        self.complete_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

in your view you call `object.set_done()` where object is the instance of `MyModel`

Comment: I'll try it know, but as it seems it'll work well. Thank you so much for your time!!